# How to use writing N for insert query in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In SQL Server

```
update incident_info 
set description = N'ဆေးလိပ်' 
where incidentid = 5
```

This query is correct in SQL Server and shows myanmar font correctly in the database.

I want to write correct query as above in below insert query.

```
sqlUtil.SqlDataUpdate(false, ("INSERT INTO Incident_Info (incidentid, incidentdate, incidenttime, description, Salesmen_id, name, phone, email, address, cost, currency, solution, status)" +
            "VALUES (@incidentid, @incidentdate, @incidenttime, N'+@description+', @salesmenid, N'+@name+', @phone, @email, N'+@address+', @cost, @currency, N'+@solution+', @status)"), SysController.dicParams);
```

Comment: You need to just **define** the parameters as `SqlDbType.NVarChar` - no need for a `N` before the parameter name..... . `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = "......"` - strings in .NET are already by default Unicode string

Answer (score 4):

You **do NOT** need to prefix your SQL parameter names with a `N` prefix - that's useless, and probably results in an error. The `N` prefix is **only** needed when specifying a Unicode **string literal** in a raw SQL code snippet.

In your case, what you need to ensure is that the code that does the actual insert into SQL Server properly defines your parameters as `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. So in your `sqlUtil` class, somewhere, you have a method `SqlDataUpdate` that parses and executes that SQL statement you send in.

Inside there, you must ensure that code something like this is used:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
{
    // here, you need to ensure you define your string parameters correctly
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    .....
    
    // and then you need to set the values - since .NET strings are inherently Unicode, no special treatment is needed
    insertCmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = SysController.dicParams.......
    .....
    
    // open, execute, close
    conn.Open();
    int rowsInserted = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This must be done **inside** your `sqlUtil` class - you **cannot** influence this from the "outside" by simply adding a `N` prefix to your parameter names...

Comment: Nice and short `insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = SysController.dicParams;` that's two lines into one. And `conn.Close(8);` is a typo